# Unable to redirect user to login page after registration using the redirect funtion in django

Tags: django

I am trying to redirect user to login page after registration and i am getting the Reverse for login not found error

accounts/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('articles/', include('articles.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('users.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

users/urls.py

```
    from . import views

    app_name = 'users'

    urlpatterns = [
        path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
        path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    ]
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    form = RegisterForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        print(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            user = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, 'Account was create for ' + user)
            return redirect('login')
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

The error i got

NoReverseMatch at /accounts/register/
Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you specified an `app_name`, you need to prefix the name of the view with that `app_name`, so it should be `redirect('users:login')`:

```
def register(request):
    form = RegisterForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        print(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            user = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, 'Account was create for ' + user)
            return redirect('users:login')
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```